# 2 computers, 2 monitors to extend displays, and a wireless keyboard and mouse

Tags: wireless, hdmi, multiple-monitors, kvm

I need a way to switch between my gaming computer and my work laptop but still be able to use both my monitors and wireless keyboard/mouse. Does anyone have any suggestions on a KVM switcher for this?

Answer (score -2):

There is a software and a hardware solution.

Symless is an affordable solution. And works more consistently than the free options out there.

You could rig up a USB splitter, but that could be too finicky to recommend without testing.